# Linux / OS X rename preserving timestamps

Tags: linux, macos, bash, touch, rename

To transfer the contents of an OS X server to a NTFS compatible one, I need to sanitize all filenames, preserving the original timestamps.

I already got as far as the following commands:

1- for the rename command
(OS X VERSION) FIRST: brew install rename

```
find "$1" -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/[\\:*?"<>|]/-/g'
```

2- for the timestamp preserving:

```
touch -r "$1" reference.tmp; mv -- "$1" "$2"; touch -r reference.tmp -- "$2"; rm reference.tmp
```

Does anybody know how I could combine both into a single script..?
All help kindly appreciated! :)

Comment: just `cp -p` will preserve the time.

Answer (score 1):

The rename that is installed by `brew install rename` (http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) seems to preserve the mtime, atime, and ctime, and creation time by default.

```
$ touch a
$ stat -f'%m %a %c %B' a
1385979835 1385979835 1385979835 1385979835
$ rename s/a/b/ *
$ stat -f'%m %a %c %B' b
1385979835 1385979835 1385979835 1385979835
```

You might also use a command like this:

```
for f in **/*; do mv -- "$f" "${f//[\\:*?\"<>|]/-}"; done
```

`**` requires bash 4.0 or later and `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: Yes, on my first test (on the Desktop) it seemed to update timestamps, but I discovered that on the server it preserved them :) Thanks for the alternative option as well!